# How do I upgrade my rooted Nexus One using OTA updates?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, clockworkmod-recovery, ota-update, root-access

I have a Nexus One that I rooted years ago. It's running "stock" Froyo. I get offered OTA updates to Gingerbread, and I'd like to do the update.

When I choose the update, it reboots the phone, which brings me to the ClockworkMod bootloader. Now what?

Can I make this work somehow?

Answer (score 1):

OTA updates can only be applied to a completely stock, non-rooted phones, using the stock recovery.

If you really want a completely stock Gingerbread, you will need to un-root your Nexus One and revert to Froyo's stock recovery.  See instructions [here](http://adrielservice.com/blog/?p=410).

Alternatively, you can flash one of the custom Gingerbread ROMs.  Some are very close to "stock" (only pre-rooted) while others like [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) offer other tweaks on top of the original.

Comment: Are you sure?  What happens when you try to get Clockwork to install the update?

Comment: Clockwork will fail to install an official OTA.  Sometimes it starts but errors out in the middle.

Comment: OK, thanks. It handles official packages nicely on my SGS so I had no idea.