# If you root a phone can you still get the upgrades to to the O/S?

Tags: updates, rooting, motorola-droid-razr

If I root my Motorola Droid Razr M, can I still get O/S upgrades?
If so, will they just happen automatically? Or do I need to install them (and if so where might I find instructions for that) ?

Comment: What version of OS/Kernal/Radio you are currently on ?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you still can update to "official versions" via [ota-update](/questions/tagged/ota-update) or otherwise, depends on multiple things. Basically, the manufacturer might include a check whether the currently installed ROM is valid -- in this case, an update will fail as you changed the `/system` partition during [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting). If no such check takes place, an update might succeed -- but you *may* have lost [root](/questions/tagged/root) access (if the update replaced the `/system` partition; tools like [OTA RootKeeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.otarootkeeper) might prove helpful in those cases).

For further details, please see e.g.

- [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575)
- [How do I upgrade my rooted Nexus One using OTA updates?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9339/16575)
- [Rooting and updating to Official Updates](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19766/16575)